# I need help identifying pieces, wooden cart, yellow cylinders, dark green cylinders, and white and blue rocket stickers?

Tags: piece-information, part-identification, set-identification

[image]

These are only a small fraction of pieces that came in a large tote I purchased at a garage sale. I'd appreciate any help with identifying what they are and which set these go to.

Answer (score 9):

Yellow half cylinders + White, yellow & grey assemblies are from:

[8037-1: Anakin's Y-wing Starfighter](https://brickset.com/sets/8037-1/Anakin-s-Y-wing-Starfighter)

[image]

Dark grey part + dark green assemblies are from:

[7930-1: Bounty Hunter Assault Gunship](https://brickset.com/sets/7930-1/Bounty-Hunter-Assault-Gunship)

[image]

White panels + light grey part + red / white striped part + cone & red 1x1's are from:

[7593-1: Buzz's Star Command Spaceship](https://brickset.com/sets/7593-1/Buzz-s-Star-Command-Spaceship)

[image]

The cart is from:

[7195-1: Ambush In Cairo](https://brickset.com/sets/7195-1/Ambush-In-Cairo)

[image]